# web application: store txt file on windows server share from linux web server

Tags: java, linux, web-applications, fileserver

I have a java class that I use to create a text file from a web application.  I'm using the following code:

```
private void CreatePaymentFile(String QueryCriteria) {
BigDecimal TotalPay;
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("00000");
String RecordString = null;
try{
String fileName = "\\\\fileandprint\\Apps\\Jury\\SHARE\\Payment_" + shortdateToday + SeqID + "24400.txt";
File f = new File(fileName);
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(f);
SetPaymentFileName("Payment_" + shortdateToday + SeqID + "24400.txt");
FileWriter PaymentStream = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(PaymentStream);

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String RecordStringFormat = "%-220s%-3s%-4s%-3s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-30s%-287s%-10s%-150s%-1s%-30s%-1s%-80s%-10s%-6s%-6s%-10s%-20s%-5s%-12s%-43s%-2s%-10s%-70s%-3s%-1s%-1s%-10s%-4s%-6s%-10s%-10s%-5s%27s";
JurorPayDetails JurorpayDetails = new JurorPayDetails();
ArrayList<JurorPayDetails.JurorPayDetailsTable> JurorPayDetailsObjList = new ArrayList<JurorPayDetails.JurorPayDetailsTable>();
JurorpayDetails.setJurorPayDetailsSql("Select P.*, GroupAssignment, TermDateServed, LastName, FirstName, Street1, Street2, City, State, ZipCode, Mileage, PublicEmployee, PayTime, PayMiles from PayDetails P INNER JOIN Jurors J ON P.JurorID = J.JurorID INNER JOIN Address A ON J.JurorID = A.JurorID where AddressType = 'M' and J.TermDateServed IN (" + QueryCriteria +") ORDER BY GroupAssignment, LastName");
boolean indicator = JurorpayDetails.setListOfJurorPayDetails();

if (indicator == true)
{
int size = JurorpayDetails.getListSize();
JurorPayDetailsObjList = JurorpayDetails.getJurorPayDetailsList();
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i){
JurorPayDetails.JurorPayDetailsTable eachPayable = JurorPayDetails.JurorPayDetailsTable)JurorPayDetailsObjList.get(i);
TotalPay = eachPayable.HoursAmount.add(eachPayable.MilesAmount);
RecordString = String.format(RecordStringFormat, ((eachPayable.Street1.trim() + " " + eachPayable.Street2.trim()).trim()), "1","B","1","WFB10","00000","21801","21801",eachPayable.City,"",longdateToday,"", "N", "21801_" + eachPayable.JurorID,"N",((eachPayable.FirstName.trim() + " " + eachPayable.LastName.trim()).trim()),"",    "PYMTLD","0",longdateToday,"21801" + shortdateToday + SeqID,df2.format(i + 1),eachPayable.Zipcode,"","RE","0","","CHK","N", "Y",longdateToday,"PYMT",eachPayable.State, "","001","01200",Paymentdf.format(TotalPay));
out.append(RecordString);
out.newLine();
}
out.close();
}
}catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
```

not a big thing, run a query, get the results and write them in a fixed format to a file and store it on one of our Windows servers.

This works fine when run locally, however, when we put the application on the Linux web server (and change the settings to Linux), the files are not stored in the correct network location.

I have tried using Windows file notation and Linux file notation:
\\fileandprint\Apps\Jury\SHARE\
and
//fileandprint/Apps/Jury/SHARE/

and yes the file location does exist, as I said when run locally in development it works, only when it's on the Linux box does it not store the files correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to explicitly mount the network share into a local directory. Please see http://linuxwiki.de/smbmount for an explanation on how to do this.

Directly accessing the network share works in the Gnome and KDE file managers because they apply some magic themselves. On the operating system level those pathes don't exist.

If this does not solve the issue, please attach the exception output. You can change

```
System.err.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
```

to

```
err.printStackTrace();
```

This will include the exception name and stacktrace in addition to the message. This is especially helpful because the message may be null and you can easily see in which line of your code the exception occurred.

Comment: If you mean that the Windows network share needs to be accessible from the Linux PC, that is already done.  I can use TightVNC to get to the Linux box, open the file system and see Fileandprint on the Linux Network Share.

Comment: How did you "open the filesystem"? I am asking because a number of gname/kde related programs can access network shares directly although java cannot.

Comment: I log onto the Linux box with the root user.  I open Root's Home from the desktop, which gets me the File Browser.  From there I click on Network Servers...from there I can see the FileandPrint server and get to the network.  I believe though that we have found a work around using a Jitterbit Windows server to create the documents and move them.

Comment: That is exactly the non comparable test case I have been talking about. The File Browser is showing you things the operating system does know nothing about. But it is good that you found another workaround.